# Jquery serialize yields nothing on Ajax Submit

Tags: jquery

Why does `serialize()` produce nothing below?

Does it not work with `type=file`? If not, how do I post my data?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileload" name="fileform"  
                                        action="/bounce" method=POST>
Select JSON File:<br> 
          <input id="fname" type="file" name="fdata" /><br>
          <input type="submit" name="abutton" value="Load" />
        </form>

$(function() {
  $('#fileload[name=fileform]').submit(function(e){
  // or $('form[name=fileform]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var v= $(this).serialize();
    console.log('V' +  v) ;
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
    alert(json);
    }, 'text');
  return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: It will not read a local file, you need to process the file on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery cannot read a local file, if you want to get the filename + path however:

```
$(function(){
$('#fileload[name=fileform]').submit(function(e){
// or $('form[name=fileform]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var v= $(this).serialize()+$('#fname').attr('name')+'='+$('#fname').val();
    console.log('V' +  v) ;
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), v, function(json) {
    alert(json);
    }, 'text');
return false;

}); });
```

Comment: <input id="fname" type="file" name="fdata" /><br>  This reads the local file

Comment: I mean you can't access a local file using JS, you have to send it to the server and read it back

Comment: That's what the submit it for, I am bouncing it off the server.

Comment: But the server sees nothing

Comment: This on the other hand works great and I get my json data bounced back   $.post($(this).attr('action'), {"fdata": '{"aa":"bb"}' }, function(json) {

Comment: and using the changes I suggested (manually adding the fields name and value because serialize() doesn't catch it)? p.s. you might want to try using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload